# Trying to loop through a predefined range when creating blank text files

Tags: python, for-loop

Long time visitor, first time posting. I'm learning Python through Automate the Boring Stuff and came across something that I wanted to 'automate' for future use but I'm a bit stuck.

What I want to do is run a script that will create a predefined number of text files. I have been doing some browsing and pieced together a script that will create a new text file but will only create one.

```
import os
i = 0

while os.path.exists("newFile%s.txt" % i):
i += 1

newFile = open('newFile%s.txt' % i, 'w')      # creates the file
newFile.write('This file is meaningless.')
newFile.close()
```

This works fine, but when I try to use a for loop to cycle this command 7 times, I get the output: newFile[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].txt
This is my for loop code as an example:

```
numbers = range(0,7)                  

for i in numbers:                       
    while os.path.exists("newFile%s.txt" % i):
        numbers += 1

newFile = open('newFile%s.txt' % numbers, 'w')      
newFile.write('This file is meaningless.')
newFile.close()
```

Can anyone help understand why it's giving me "newFile[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].txt" with that for loop and what I can do to complete what I want?

Comment: I did notice by testing your code, that you are running python 2.
If you are learning, I recommend learning python 3, python 2 is kept around only for compatibility with older code.

Comment: Thanks Arthur, didn't know about that but will be doing that from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the for loop you don't need to increment the variable manually but you are still incrementing the wrong variable (`numbers` in this case) manually. That is the job of the for loop. In the first case, you had to do it manually because you were using a while loop to check the number of files.

In your second case, the combination of `for` and `while` loop doesn't make sense to me.

`numbers += 1` will also throw the following error because `numbers` is a range and you are adding 1 to it which is an `int` (integer) type.

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'range' and 'int'

Also, you can simply use `range(7)` which by default starts from 0. You can also use it directly in the for loop without using an additional variable to store the range (`numbers` here)

Use the following version where you remove the incremental part

```
for i in range(7):                       
    if os.path.exists("newFile%s.txt" % i):
        newFile = open('newFile%s.txt' %i, 'w')      
        newFile.write('This file is meaningless.')
        newFile.close()
```

Comment: I do believe the `numbers += 1` part was meant to skip files that had already been created, not to write only to files that already existed.

Comment: @ArthurMoraesDoLago: `numbers += 1` will not work for reasons I mentioned. `numbers` is a range. Perhaps the OP wanted it to be `i`, in that case, he/she should use `continue`

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the errors, just wanted to point out that the code doesn't do exactly what he asked I think. He said 'create a predefined number of text files', so it might be necessary to drop range and iterate manually if he wants to create 7 new files, even if some files with that naming structure already exist.

Comment: I guess by predefined he/she meant the number 7. Let's wait for the OP to jump in and say what is expected and what is correct or not. Things seem a bit unclear at the moment

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I tried running your code but no files were created and no error showed. I added a couple print statements to see where this was failing and saw that the if statement was not running. Looking at Arthur's post, I tried "if not" for the if statement and that did the trick. Not sure why, so I'll do some research on if not statements.

Answer (score 0):

This is also my first time answering. I'll try to explain as clearly as I can. I'm assuming your script isn't actually like the first code in your post because there is no indentation there, python should throw an error running that. With the correct indentation, it should run just fine.

There are a few things wrong with your second script. I'll walk through them one by one. First of all, your script shouldn't run. Python should complain with a `TypeError` at the `numbers += 1` line. You are trying to add `int` to `range`.

For a for-loop you don't have to increment the index variable. `i` will iterate through `numbers`. You're getting "newFile[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].txt" is because the for-loop fails. It's easy to understand just by walking through the script line by line. First, `numbers` is set to `range(0,7)`. The for-loop doesn't do anything and python gives `TypeError`. In the line `newFile = open('newFile%s.txt' % numbers, 'w')`, `numbers` is `range(0,7)` and python will create "newFile[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].txt".

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, the correct code would look like the one posted by @Bazingaa.

```
import os

for i in range(0,7):
    if os.path.exists("newFile%s.txt" % i):
        newFile = open("newFile%s.txt" % i)
        newFile.write("This file is meaningless.")
        newFile.close()
```

Hope my answer helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I'll include an answer with my interpretation of your question. As I understand it, you want to create 7 new files, no matter how many files were already created. So if you begin with *newFile3.txt* and *newFile4.txt*, after running the program, you will have all *newFileX.txt* with X going from 0 to 8, total 9 files.

In this case, your code only has some problems with using the wrong variable and wrong indentation. This should work:

```
import os

numbers = range(0,7)                  

for i in numbers:                       
    while os.path.exists("newFile%s.txt" % i):
        i += 1

    newFile = open('newFile%s.txt' % i, 'w')      
    newFile.write('This file is meaningless.')
    newFile.close()
```

However, in a scenario where lots of files with these names already exist, you will run this while loop many times checking for the same files. I would personally prefer to iterate by hand in this scenario, also opening the file in the recommended way:

```
import os

i = 0 # holds which newFileX number we are trying to create
count = 0 # holds number of created files
while count < 7:
    if not os.path.exists("newFile%s.txt" % i):
        # Open file an write to it
        with open('newFile%s.txt' % i, 'w') as newFile:
            newFile.write('This file is meaningless.\n')
        count += 1 # We just created a file so increase count
    i += 1
```

Also, I already commented on this, but if you are learning, you should learn python 3. There aren't that many differences, but Python 3 is the future, Python 2 is kept around for compatibility with older code.